# Extract instagram link in bio

Tags: javascript, parsing, instagram, extract, server-side

I'm trying to extract the link shared in an instagram bio page (a class="_ng0lj").

How do I request this server side and forward my end-user to it every time they come on my site (ie cross-domain issue so would like to extract server side).

Comment: Do you have full access over your server? As in are you limited to what software you can or not install? Also how fast would this transaction of data have to be?

Comment: @YAHsaves thanks for replying. I actually want to extract instagram bio link from my wordpress site so user will be redirected to link. It is important for me to get the instagram redirection link instead of direct landing page (ie end page)